# Start firefox from a terminal window, open a text file and position the text shown at a specified line

Tags: firefox, browser, fortran, command-line-interface

I would like to improve the help facility in a Fortran program by opening the user guide in a separate browser (Firefox) window whenever the user type a ?
as answer to a question the program asks.

I can use call system('path/firefox -file user_guide.hlp')

to open the help file.  But additionally I would like to position the text in the browser window at a specified line in the help text.

I know which lines in the help file that should be relevant for the user because inside the Fortran program I keep track of the commands the user has made (I use a command line interface, no GUI).  At present I print these lines in the terminal window running the program but this limits the amount of lines I can print and obscures the program output.  With the whole user guide available in a separate window the user may also easily search for additional explanations elsewhere in the user guide, I do not expect he or she will voluntarily read the user guide.

Thanks for any help

Bo Sundman

Comment: Note system is not standard Fortran. You might want to look at execute_command_line, see e.g. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/692784

Comment: I am quite sure system is standard Fortran 2008 or later

Comment: BoSundman : no, as @IanBush said, it is not standard Fortran, see, e.g., its gfortran documentation, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM.html . execute_command_line is the intrinsic subroutine introduced by Fortran 2008 for that purpose, and the last draft for the next version of the standard (document N2146 in https://wg5-fortran.org/documents.html) does not mention any intrinsic "system" subroutine.

Comment: Right, one learns a little every day

Comment: Assuming you're on Linux (as you use "path/firefox" and not "path\firefox") you can use "xdg-open", this will open the page using the users preferred browser. On OSX, "open" does the same, FWIW. Also, no need to use an explicit path, those two should be found in the users default $PATH.

Comment: is "xdg-open" a call I can make inside my Fortran program instead of execute_command_line?  I have worried how to know which browser to use but I try to take one step at a time.

Comment: No, xdg-open is the name of a binary, which looks up the users preferred application from the MIME app specs. See https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/

Answer (score 4):

You cannot go to specific lines but you could try using named anchor tabs.  In the help file,

```
<a name="1"/>
help topic 1
<a name="2"/>
help topic 2
```

When you issue your call to firefox, to go to anchor 2

```
system('path/firefox -file user_guide.html#2')
```

This should work on all browsers.  The newer ones will also take id= instead of name=

**EDIT**
If the above doesn't work, try

```
system('path/firefox "file://path/user_guide.html#2"')
```

**EDIT 2**
If both the firefox path and html file path have spaces, on Windows, 8.3 filenames can be used.  Use dir/x to find out what the 8.3 filenames are.  Alternatively filenames with spaces can be used; the syntax is pretty weird

```
 call execute_command_line('""C:\...\firefox.exe" "file://x:\...\userguide.html#2""')
```

1. start string with '
2. Use 2 double quotes for the first double quote ""
3. Add your pathname to firefox
4. Use 1 double quote to terminate the path name
5. add a space
6. Use 1 double quote to start the parameter
7. Add the parameter
8. Use 2 double quotes to terminate
9. end the string with '

Comment: Thank you, that seem what I need, I will test.

Comment: Remember to add in the other HTML tags like <html>, <head> and <body>

Comment: The original user guide is a LaTeX file but I can generate both PDF or HTML from this.  If there is a way to include "anchor tabs" for the HTML version in the LaTeX file?  If so that would simplify maintaining the user guide.

Comment: Hm, it does not work.  With the #n after the file name the help file is not found, without it opens the first page of the html file.  My html file is generated from a LaTeX file using htlatex and I just added a few <a name="n"/> manually.

Comment: Does the filename end with .htm or .html?  Adding hrefs - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230112/reference-to-local-html-file-with-anchor-hashmark-via-href

Comment: I have looked at the link and tried all possible combinations referring to a name= or id= with just # or \# or #nameddest= etc to no avail.  I have also tested various ways to specify name= or id= in the html file (inclusive both htm and html as extension).

Comment: If you just try "path/firefox -file userguide.html#x" on the command line, does it work

Comment: FWIW, I've tried the same and it works if I type the file name explicitly in the URL bar (i.e., ...html#3 etc). But if I do it from the command line (firefox -file ...html#3), it fails for some reason (it shows %233 etc in the URL bar), on Mac.

Comment: @Bo Are you running this from a Linux or Windows environment?

Comment: I am testing on Windows, the software is multiplatform.  I get the same error %253 in the firefox window.

Comment: I am trying to shortcut reading a lot of documentation here ... I am not an advanced LaTeX user and the last time I generated a HTML file must have been more than 20 years ago typing everything on the keyboard.  I find now I can generate both PDF and HTML from the same LaTeX file which is very nice.  But I assume I have to add \hypertarget{target-label} in my LaTeX document and then generate the HTML file in order to use #target-label to find this place in te HTML file from my Fortran command line?

Comment: If a start firefox and type file:///helpfil#target-label that works.  But if I type in my terminal window path\firefox -file helpfile#target-label that does not work.  the browser answers if cannot find the file with that name with %23larget-label as a suffix.

Comment: I've modified my answer.  There is an alternative syntax using file://

Comment: Wow, that works. Thanks. But one has to provide the whole path to the help file.  Thanks a lot, this improves on-line help a lot and maybe some will actually read the user guide.

Comment: Well, it works from a terminal window but when I use exactly the same string in a call to execute_command_string it seems as I am not allowed to have " both around the "path/firefox" and "file://path/helpfile#anchor"..  Without the first "" Windows does not find firefox and without the latter it ignores the #anchor.  With all 4 " it does not find firefox.   Suck

Comment: I'll see if I can find a fix for that.  In the mean time, you could try 8.3 filenames.  The 8.3 names do not need quotes.  Do a dir/x and it will tell you what the 8.3 name is.  See if that works.

Comment: Modified answer if you do not wish to use 8.3 filenames

Comment: I am old enough to remember the 8.3 filenames, I did not know they still existed.  So with Explorer it works also from Fortran using #name.  If you have further hints please send me an email.  I have to test this on linux also ...